# What is the grammatical function of the phrase 'to Hyundai' in the following context?

Tags: grammar

> So important is the Australian market **to Hyundai** these days that
> we were chosen as the first in the world to receive this new SR model.

Is the phrase 'to Hyundai' a complement of the adjective word '**important**'? Or, is it an adverbial modifier of the verb '**is**'?

Comment: The first: 'So important is to Hyundai the Australian market' would be incorrect. You can also see by writing 'The Australian market is important (to Hyundai).'

Comment: 'So important is the Australian market to Hyundai' is an inversion sentence that can be modified as 'The Australian market is very important to Hyundai'.

Comment: No, the _so_ requires a complement _that_ clause: _The Australian market is **so** [important to Hyundai]  these days **that we were chosen as the first**_  The bracketed _to Hyundai_ modifies _important_, showing whose importance is being discussed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a complement of the adjective "important". There is an inversion of the subject and the verb and an extraposed prepositional complement. The sentence is written usually as follows.

- The Australian market is so important to Hyundai these days that we were chosen as the first in the world to receive this new SR model. (*prepositional complement in the usual place*)
- So important  to Hyundai  is the Australian market these days that we were chosen as the first in the world to receive this new SR model.

The other function considered (adverbial modifier), however, besides the fact that it is not right from the point of view that "to" introduces the complement of an adjective, is not right also because "important" is not an adverb but an adjective; also, adverbs do not modify a copula according to certain experts.

Comment: Thank you very much! The knowledge 'adverbs do not modify a copula' is especially useful!

Comment: Additional question: If  'to Hyundai' is a complement of the adjective "important", then what is the grammatical component of the part 'that...new SR Model' in this sentence?

Comment: @Winter'sLove This is a clause that is introduced by the correlative subordinator "so…that".

Comment: I know this construct 'so...that' and the part 'that...' is a clause, but I don't know what does the second part 'that...' modify? I think it is a complement to the adjective 'important' too, or to the adverb 'So' according to someone on my other thread in the Wordreference forum.

Comment: There is no extraposition here. Extraposition would involve the use of a substitute item in the position where the unit in question originated (Oxford Dictionary of English Grammar p152).

Comment: @DW256 Possibly, you regard extraposition  as a somewhat  stricter principle. From what says [Wikepedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extraposition#Examples) this would be a case of extraposition: "b. Some guy was there with red hair. - Extraposition of prepositional phrase out of subject".  Even, if I don't agree with this particular example, it is of the type in the OP's sentence. (mechanism of syntax that alters word order in such a manner that a relatively "heavy" constituent appears to the right of its canonical position. Extraposing a constituent results in a discontinuity […].) (1/2)

Comment: @DW256 What would be the name you give to this principle according to the grammar you are referring to? (2/2)

Answer (score 0):

The prepositional phrase *so important* is serving the function of an adjunct adverbial.  It modifies the entirety of the clause, *So important is the Australian market*, by providing additional information about the circumstances in which the market is so important.

*See*, [The Adjunct Adverbial in the English Grammar](https://parentingpatch.com/adjunct-adverbial-english-grammar/):  "Adjunct adverbials are words, phrases, and clauses that modify an entire clause by providing additional information about time, place, manner, condition, purpose, reason, result, and concession."

Comment: Thank you very much! 

" time, place, manner, condition, purpose, reason, result, and concession" are all nouns, but "important" is an adjective. So, does "that..." still modifies an entire clause?